# Saving image in python using urllib

Tags: python, pyramid, urllib, waitress

I am trying to save an image from the web using urllib and I keep getting this error :

```
[Wed Oct 17 10:03:43 2012] [error] [client 223.232.227.124] urllib.urlretrieve(image,ban)
[Wed Oct 17 10:03:43 2012] [error] [client 223.232.227.124]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
[Wed Oct 17 10:03:43 2012] [error] [client 223.232.227.124]     return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
[Wed Oct 17 10:03:43 2012] [error] [client 223.232.227.124]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 243, in retrieve
[Wed Oct 17 10:03:43 2012] [error] [client 223.232.227.124]     tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
[Wed Oct 17 10:03:43 2012] [error] [client 223.232.227.124] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/public/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/project-0.0-py2.6.egg/project/images/series/graphical/104281-g2.jpg'
```

The code :

```
ban='/public/env/project/project/images/series/%s'%(banner)
image='http://www.thetvdb.com/banners/%s'%(banner)
urllib.urlretrieve(image,ban)
```

The code is working perfectly fine on my localhost using Pyramid waitress server as well as using mod_wsgi too but not on production server.

I am using Pyramid framework for development.

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to write the image there.

Answer (score 2):

This is a permissions issue. You do not have permission to write to the place that you are trying to in the server. Try someother location where you have permissions or set the proper permissions to that directory.

```
urlretrieve(url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None)
```

The second argument is the filename you want to write to. Since you are running from webapp, the process which is running the webapp should have permission to the location where you trying to write.

Comment: But why is it to trying to save in the python egg folder ? I am very new to Python.

Comment: Not sure, why the egg folder is coming in between. Try to give an absolute path to the folder were you want it to write.

Comment: I did try it. Same problem. It tries to save in egg folder only.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the absolute path above might not work since it's still in your "env" it might not even exist. use `ban = "/tmp/%s" % banner`

Comment: oh yeah, he could be in his sandboxed environment. In that case, playing with relative path for the location may help.